# Add room DB migration only for Debug build

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

my function to create DB is like so:

```
    operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
        instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
    }
```

And buildDatabase:

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(context, 
AppDatabase::class.java, "Rides.db")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
        .build()
```

What I need is that MIGRATION_2_3 only will happen in debug mode, something like this (pseudo):

```
 private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(context, 
 AppDatabase::class.java, "Rides.db")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
    if (BuildConfig.Debug)
    {
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
    }
       
        .build()
}
```

What is the proper syntax for achieving this without creating two buildDatabase functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already mentioned the pseudo code for it . you can get the builder and add the condition and then return `builder.build()`.

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context):AppDatabase {
        val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "Rides.db"
        )
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
        }
        return builder.build()
    }
```

OR

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "Rides.db"
        ).apply {
            addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
            }
        }.build()
```